# Firebase Authentication: Remove auto-login upon signing up

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am utilizing Firebase Authentication to build a sign-up function on my website that can only be accessed by admin users so that not everyone can simply sign up for an account.

The issue I am facing now is that upon signing up for an account, the code makes it so that the registered account will automatically be logged in which overrides the current logged in admin account.

Thus, I am trying to make it so that upon signing up, the code will not auto login the user.

Appreciate any help on this!

```
const auth = firebase.auth();

//sign up
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault();

  //get user info from form
  const email = signupForm['signup-email'].value + "@sbe.com";
  const password = signupForm['signup-password'].value;

  // sign up the user
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
    return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
      nric: signupForm['signup-nric'].value,
      rank: signupForm['signup-rank'].value,
      name: signupForm['signup-name'].value
    });
    }).then(() => {
      //const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-signup');
      //M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
      $('#modal-signup').modal('hide')
      signupForm.reset();
      signupForm.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = '';
    }).catch(err => {
      signupForm.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = err.message;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to make it so that upon signing up, the code will not auto login the user.

That's not possible.  When you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` on a web client, it always automatically signs in that user. The web client SDK was designed so that users can create their own accounts using credentials they provide for themselves.

If you are trying to create an account for some other user to use, you shouldn't use the client SDK for that.  You should instead invoke a backend you control and use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [create the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user).  When an account is created using your backend, it will not affect the currently signed in account on the frontend.

Comment: He can use firebase functions for that if he doesn't want to involve an external server.

Comment: @The_ehT I said "backend", not "server". Cloud Functions is one of many possible choices for a backend.

Comment: ok. Can you please give an example of a backend that would be a great fit for this?

Comment: @The_ehT Any backend that you prefer that runs any of the environments supported by the Admin SDK.  Google has Cloud Run, Compute Engine, App Engine.  AWS has Lambda and other choices.  Azure.  Cloudera.  The list is huge.  You are just setting up an API endpoint, and they all do that these days.